# How can I extract a PNG from a delphi XE5 firemonkey style?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to change the color used when elements of the MetropolisUIBlack.Style XE5 style (Firemonkey). It seems that, in order to do so, the simplest way would be to edit the PNG image that contains all these elements i the style (MetroBluestyle.png).

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to save the PNG that is contained in the style element to a file so I can manipulate it safely and reload it once the color has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Bitmap Style Designer provided with the product.
You can find it in the Tools menù and, once started, you simply have to open the MetropolisUIBlack.vsf file, select the "style.png" item under Images and click the Export button (above the right panel where you can see a preview of the picture).
Edit the picture with your favorite editor (i.e. The Gimp), save the picture, and load it back in the style using the Update button (just left the Export one).
You can save your style with a different name and use it as usual.

HTH

Comment: It's almost what I needed actually: that tool cannot open Firemonkey styles, only VCL styles.

Comment: The tool can edit both VCL and FMX styles (look here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Bitmap_Style_Designer ). I think you are confusing bitmap styles versus vector graphic styles...

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless there is some special operation to perform to enable it or convert format, that bitmap style designer provided with XE5 R2 can only open files with the vsf extension (vcl styles). It can save them to a firemonkey .style file but it can't import it.